# Using AI/ML in PDF text mining

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk, reinforcement-learning

I am newbie when it comes to NLP since I am just starting to learn about it. So, if the question seems simplistic, please bear with me :)

I have bunch of PDF files (a lot) and the task is : whenever someone ask a question and answer is available within one of those PDFs, either that section containing answer is extracted or the page number of that particular PDF is shown as the answer. You can think of each PDF as a manual for a certain product; and in total there are hundreds of PDF files.

I know that this problem can be easily solved using a PDF search engine; but is there any potential approach from text mining and AI/ML perspective that could solve the problem ? May be I train the model on few PDFs and it works for rest ?

Recently I have been trying to do some research and what I have got so far is: Whenever someone asks a question, I can extract keywords from the question using nltk python (plenty of resources available online). But what is really bothering me is the next part, where pdf text/information comes into play.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe more a question for here: [AI StackExchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @SBylemans thanks I will post the question there. So Should I remove the question from here. Or is it fine, if its still here .

Comment: you could leave it here, but the people at AI StackExchange maybe better suited to answer your question :)

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I would start with collecting or creating the data that you need to train your machine.

Such as:
1. A customers query contains the following keywords `house` `timber` `nails`.
So you search the documents for those keywords, then you send them a `house_timber.pdf`
2. Then you would want to get feedback to know if what you have done is correct or wrong.
Such as asking the customer to give you feedback on the results.
Or you can go through it yourself and train it yourself for the first few hundred / thousand times.

I would then store all these training queries and results in a database, so that each time a new query comes in, you can go through the training and come up with the most accurate answer.
Then ask for feedback again and store that new result in the database. (Continue that feedback loop!)

You could train it a fair bit yourself, by running tests.

Like give it keywords, check if those keywords exist in a `.pdf` and then mark the result as `yes [1]` or `no [0]` depending on the result.

I've found that the more you train it, the more accurate it will be. And as long as you continue to train it from the feedback then your results will continue to improve in accuracy.

I have also found that if you give it too much training data, and make it run the variations to many times. The results don't improve much and it just takes more time. So trying to find the sweet spot of, the right amount of data and the right amount of training iterations is also important. (If you are trying to give a quick response).

It's a cool adventure to start using machine learning to find patterns. Have fun!

Comment: Could you explain the point more about searching the pdf. Like how this part should be done. Should I do some indexing for all the documents and store the results somewhere or just you mean raw search on pdf ?

Comment: Depends on your programming language of choice. Most languages have libraries on converting pdf to documents or txt files. Then you could search those. 
If your data is in another format, and gets converted to pdf, then you could search that.
Or like you mentioned, you could tag PDFs.

I'd personally: 1. convert them to text; 2. store the text in a database; 3. Index them into elastic search and; 4. do a search using elasticSearch. 
So it's lighting fast and accurate. 
Hope this helps.